# How can I remove extra space between <span> children of an <h2>?

Tags: html, css

Here's the codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGwwLW

Why is there what looks like an extra line of space between the first and second subtitle? Can I get rid of it without changing the HTML structure?

This is what I use:

```
<h2>        
    <a href="#" rel="bookmark">Heading</a>
    <br><span class="subtitle">Subtitle 1</span>
    <br><span class="subtitle">March 30, 2015</span>
</h2>
```

(The subtitle is set to a smaller font size.)

Comment: you can remove the `<br/>`'s and set a `display: block;` for the `.subtitle`

Comment: Do you want to keep the <br/> or you can remove them?

Comment: I want to keep the <br /> for semantic reasons…

Comment: If I remove the <br /> — say that the CSS doesn't load for some reason: the H2 would read very strangely. Also, we have this pattern implemented on our site in many places.

But if I were to do this from scratch, I'd probably use a <header> element with an <h2> inside, and <p>s forming the subtitles. That or egrunin's approach with the <div>s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I add an extra space inside the span at the end of the first subtitle, e.g.

```
<br /><span class="subtitle">Subtitle Text </span>
```

… it fixes the problem (which I saw in Chrome and Safari, btw). It's an odd solution and I don't know why it works, but it does.

The solutions with different HTML were fine, just not what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure what your doing here;

But.. I would remove `<br>` and build it out with `<li>`

```
<h2>content</h2>
    <ul>
    <li>content<li>
    <li>content<li>
    </ul>
```

then just style your `li { line-height:1.5; }`

*Could just be a preference but feel it's a nicer flow with more flexibility.*

Answer (score 1):

Set a line height to `h2` like this http://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/ns3u7uf5/6/

**css**

```
h2 {
    font-size: 1.625rem;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
}

.subtitle {
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #818181;
    line-height: .6rem;
}
```

Comment: This actually still leaves more space in between the subtitles than I want -- but thanks for the attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, remove `<br>` and add `display:block;` to `.subtitle`.

**html**

```
<h2>        
    <a href="#" rel="bookmark">Heading</a>
    <span class="subtitle">Subtitle 1</span>
    <span class="subtitle">March 30, 2015</span>
</h2>
```

**css**

```
.subtitle {
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #818181;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    display:block;
}
```

Here is a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdggXV

Answer (score 1):

If you change

```
<br><span style="subtitle">...</span>
```

to

```
<div style="subtitle">...</div>
```

it will work the way you want: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdggPV)

Comment: He asked "Can I get rid of it without changing the HTML structure?" you changed the HTML.

Comment: But if I was up for changing the HTML, I might use this!

Comment: "Changing the HTML structure" can mean a lot of things, I figured it hurt nobody to offer this solution.